# How do you jump to or find a folder?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

On my laptop I'm forced to use the web version of Google Drive. Once I have My Drive displayed, and have opened the "master folder" that contains 75 sub folders, the only way I know to move to the desired sub folder is to scroll, which is slow.

Is there a way to jump to a folder, or **search for only a folder**, by typing a word in its name? For example, there might be 3 folders that begin with Sony: Sony KDL32R, Sony Vegas, and Sony BDP‑S3500.

Scrolling down to the "S" section requires several full drags of the scroll bar. Cumbersome.

Searching merely for "Sony" brings up lots of docs that contain that word. Locating the desired folder among the results is cumbersome. I realize that if I could make the search more specific, like "Sony Vegas", the results would be more targeted but the folder names aren't always that simple and I rarely remember their exact names.

Suggestions?

Comment: In the search, just type in the FULL folder folder name or a part of it and it should list up top.  This works fine for me on Drive.Google.com with slews of subfolders, etc. You have to type in more of the folder name and not just the part where you have slews of other folders with that same string in those folders such as "sony" to try "Sony Vegas" or Just "Vegas" and so on... works just fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for "Sony type:folder"